# Is it possible to design a digital filter that rejects 60Hz noise while keeping step response in the time domain below one mili-second

Tags: filter-design

Have been trying to design IIR and FIR 60Hz notch filters but all have step response way above 10ms.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! Your question is a little terse. Can you add some pictures or equations to it to explain what problems you are having.  I'm not sure what you mean by `~1ms step response` in the title, for example.

Comment: Hi Peter, the step response of a filter in the time domain is the time that the output takes to settle, in response to an abrupt change of value at the input (or step). 1ms is the measure of time equal to one mili-second. I clarified this. The question is in the tittle, is that the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trade off steepness of the notch against time domain ringing. That's a fundamental trade off and there is no way around it. When using an IIR notch you can simply adjust the "Q" (quality factor). A Q of 3 will give a step response that's roughly 10ms long.